# Watterott RPi-Display TFT no output

Tags: video, display, framebuffer

since a few days I'm a proud owner of a RPi Model B+ and a [2,8" RPi-Display from Watterott](http://www.watterott.com/index.php?page=product&info=3530). HDMI output works fine, I am using a preinstalled Raspbian that boots into desktop.

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/watterott/RPi-Display/blob/master/docu/FBTFT-Install.md) to set up the display. 
As soon as I get to *Step 3: Activate Framebuffer*, the displays's backlight turns on, but nothing more. `con2fbmap 1 1` does absolutely nothing, `FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb1 startx &` lets the HDMI output disappear for a few seconds, and then returns with all programs closed.

Any ideas what could be the problem? Apparently I am a rather new to the linux world.

When I use rpi-fbcp (github.com/tasanakorn/rpi-fbcp) to simply mirror the HDMI output to the display, it works, so the hardware seems to be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you exactly running `con2fbmap 1 1` after the display drivers are loaded?

If the desktop runs on HDMI also with the Framebuffer set to fb1, then there is an option in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-fbturbo.conf`.
Look for the line `Option "fbdev" "/dev/fb0"` and remove/comment it.
It is this issue: https://github.com/notro/fbtft/issues/63

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That partially solves to problem, after commenting out that line I can now put the screen on the rpi-display with `FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb1 startx &`. However, `con2fbmap 1 1` still does nothing. I run it exactly after `sudo modprobe fbtft dma` and `sudo modprobe fbtft_device name=rpi-display speed=32000000 rotate=270`.

Comment: I just got `con2fbmap 1 1` to work! My fault was not to boot into console and I tried to run the command at the desktop terminal, whoops.

Comment: Nice to hear that it is now working.
I have also updated the documentation with more infos.